# can't disable droppable in jquery ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, droppable

I am using jquery ui Draggable and Droppable in my web application to drag divs and drop them,

But when I drop the items on the droppale area (they are sometimes textboxes or textareas) I can't react with them any more or drag them further, its like they are consumed in that part of the page.

other thing is that I decided to totaly disable the droppable but still the div keeps dropping stuff on it and consuming them, i tried also to delete the droppable event from the code and run it again still the same thing keeps happenning.

but when i drag them to other parts of the page the drag works fine.
I also tried to run on several machines but still same output.

what could be the cause of the problem ?

code for creating the draggables

```
$('body').append("<div id='addNewText'></div>");
    $("#addNewText").draggable();
```

code for creating the droppable page but when I deleted the droppable part.

```
$("#book").append("<div name=\"page\" id =\"page"+(pagesNumber+1)+"\"> </div>");
    $("#page"+(pagesNumber+1)).css("position","absolute");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set "disabled" property, something like this:

```
$("#addNewText").droppable('option', 'disabled');
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question and doesn't help the OP.

Comment: He asked about "How to disable droppable". I answered.